# How to list all cells in grid?

Tags: extjs

for example:

> for row in rows:
>
> for col in cols:
>
> ```
>  print cell[row,col]
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an [`Ext.data.Store`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.Store) from your grid (or in general), you can interate through through it as follows:

```
var store = grid.getStore();

var records = store.getRange();

for(var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    for(var index in records[i]) {
        if (records[i].hasOwnIndex(index)) {
            //not sure how you want to print this, so for now, print to console
            console.log(records[i][index])
        }
    }
}
```

...However, if you have an `Ext.grid.GridPanel`, I'm not sure why you would want to do this manually...